# CSS Sprites on top of .body background image

Tags: css, background-image, sprite

This is something that probably has a simple (2 letter) answer, but if I have a page with a background image is it possible to use sprites on top of it?  It seems like no, but it's such a simple thing it's hard to believe it's not possible.

Comment: It would be easy enough to use a `<div>` with absolute positioning?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can stack as many elements with background images as you like on top of each other. You can position them and use z-index to control the stacking order of them (higher numbers are stacked above lower numbers). As long as you define the widths/heights and background position of your sprites correctly, it will work.

Remember elements need to have position for a z-index to work (position: relative; or position: absolute;).